# Parallel examples with glosses on same line

Tags: linguistics, examples, gb4e, cgloss4e

I'm writing a linguistics paper and I need to use the example environment a lot. I have noticed in some papers that examples are presented in parallel, that is with 2 different examples starting on the same line, with glosses under, but I have no idea of how to achieve that myself. I enclose a snip from a paper to illustrate what I mean and what I would like to achieve.

I use the `cgloss4e` and `gb4e` packages for example, and the documentation that I've found does not provide any information on this.

A MWE would be:

```
\documentclass[12]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cgloss4e}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

Some text. 

\begin{exe} 

\ex \gll Ein hund \\ a dog \\
\ex \gll Un chien \\ a dog \\ 
\end{exe} 

\end{document}
```

The two examples follow each other, although I would want them to be on the same line.

I've found no questions on this issue on this forum. Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: As a matter of fact, it does! Simpler than expected. By loading the \multicol package and using \begin{multicols}{2} right after \ex, I get the right result. Thanks!